# How to implement a function to retrieve all arguments for calls to a method in a project with C#?

Tags: c#

Implement a function that retrieves all the arguments for calls to MethodA(string a) in a project. For example, if there are two calls to MethodA("1") and MethodA("2"), the method should return ["1", "2"].

```
MethodA("1");
MethodA("2');
GetAllMethodArguments("MethodA"); //return ["1","2"]
```

I tried using reflexes, but there seems to be no way to do that.

Comment: Why on Earth do you need to do this? You basically need to analyse the entire application's IL, find all method calls to the method, and then find the values of arguments that are passed. Considering that I could do something like (`MethodA(((char)48).ToString())`), you'll also have to consider all the different ways those input values can be created if you hope to capture values beyond literals. It might not even be possible if you call `MethodA(resultOfHttpCall)`, etc. Either way, it doesn't make much sense to do it.

Comment: I reckon Roslyn is your friend here.

Comment: `_logger.Info()` ...

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama The project requires tts, where the tts files are obtained from an API and cached locally. However, since the API is very slow, I intend to cache all the files locally during project startup.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that you're going about this the wrong way then. Why not have a service that provides the required data via properties in some centrally maintained class. You'll have all the details in one place and won't need to implement something overly complicated to work out what tts files are being used.

Comment: Very enlightening,thanks @ProgrammingLlama 编程骆驼

Answer (score 4):

This is something you could do at build time with a Roslyn analyzer, although note that many times: the values could be non-constant expressions that cannot be fully evaluated.

The *easiest* way of seeing all runtime values would be to change `MethodA` to log it. If that isn't an option, another Roslyn-based approach (very recently) would be to write an "interceptor" that looks for all of the `MethodA` call sites (the same as the first line above), but then emits code to redirect those calls, log, and forward them. Note that interceptors still need to obey accessibility rules, and interceptors can only impact the assembly currently being built.

---

As an example of the genetated code you'd need for the interceptor approach:

```
internal class Whatever
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MethodA("1");
        MethodA("2");
    }
    internal static void MethodA(string value) => Console.WriteLine($"usage: {value}");
}

// your build-time generated file...
namespace EvilMachinations
{
    file class Interceptors
    {
        [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InterceptsLocation("your\\path\\here\\Program.cs", 5, 9)]
        [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InterceptsLocation("your\\path\\here\\Program.cs", 6, 9)]
        internal static void HacketyHackHack(string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"interceptor: {value}");
            Whatever.MethodA(value);
        }
    }
}
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    file class InterceptsLocationAttribute(string x, int y, int z) : Attribute { }
}
```

with

```xml
<InterceptorsPreviewNamespaces>$(InterceptorPreviewNamespaces);EvilMachinations</InterceptorsPreviewNamespaces>
```

in the csproj

Comment: Smashed out of the park

Answer (score 0):

I would create a static class `MethodArgs`, with a Stack member called `argsPassedToMethod` and a static method `GetAllMethodArguments`
Example:

```
public static class MethodArgs
{
public static Stack argsPassedToMethod;
static MethodArgs() {  argsPassedToMethod = new Stack(); }
public static string[] GetAllMethodArguments => argsPassedToMethod.ToArray();
}
```

Then in Method A you can add the args passed at each call to your stack, like this

```
public void MethodA('my-arg')
{
  argsPassedToMethod.Push('my-arg');
 // etcetera, your method logic
}
```

And in your code, you can retrieve the args by calling `GetAllMethodArguments`.
You need to use `argsPassedToMethod.Clear()` when you want to reset your stack.